# Apify with Python : Account authorization key not found in the system

Tags: web-scraping, recaptcha, captcha, apify, hcaptcha

I was trying the free trial version of recaptcha solver by apify for the following page  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

**Input :**

```
{
  "key": "apify_api_KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK",
  "webUrl": "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo",
  "siteKey": "6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-"
}
```

I tried running the same with the above inputs, but I get the error

```
2022-08-14T10:13:34.970Z ACTOR: Pulling Docker image from repository.
2022-08-14T10:13:35.109Z ACTOR: Creating Docker container.
2022-08-14T10:13:35.168Z ACTOR: Starting Docker container.
2022-08-14T10:13:36.323Z 
2022-08-14T10:13:36.327Z WARNING: The npm start script not found in package.json. Using "node main.js" instead. Please update your package.json file. For more information see https://github.com/apifytech/apify-cli/blob/master/MIGRATIONS.md
2022-08-14T10:13:36.330Z 
2022-08-14T10:13:38.579Z Solving re-captcha with Anticaptcha: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
2022-08-14T10:13:38.780Z User function threw an exception:
2022-08-14T10:13:38.782Z Account authorization key not found in the system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an anti-captcha subscription to be able to use it. https://apify.com/petr_cermak/anti-captcha-recaptcha

```
"key": ANTI_CAPTCHA_KEY
```

You trying to use Apify API key to authorize access to anti-captcha.com service, it fails with error `Account authorization key not found in the system`

Comment: You need to request demo credits, see https://anti-captcha.com/faq/177_other_questions and https://anti-captcha.com/clients/finance/demo

Comment: I see you are developer at apify, you sure can help me with this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352125/how-does-2captcha-and-apify-like-captcha-solving-services-replicate-my-captcha-u