# Handle Checkbox captcha in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, captcha

I am trying to handle captcha checkbox by switching to iframe 1st with a wait of 10 sec and than clicking on the checkbox...but out of luck its not working.

Note:- Yes we know the purpose of Captcha but i was looking a way to automate it

Comment: what are you using to click the checkbox?

Comment: You mean google reCaptcha ? If yes then https://stackoverflow.com/a/75758492/1911941 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75753414/1911941 answers will help you.