# Google login using Selenium (CAPTCHA appears only in CI)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, testing, captcha

I write a test using Selenium WebDriver (JAVA) to do an authentification on a google account. It's work in local but not in the CI. When I run the test on a CI , it gets a CAPTCHA as seen in the screenshot below. I don't know how to bypass the captcha or solve this issue.

[image]

i try some solutions find on this website but without success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: alternatively, there is a google api to interact with gmail etc, to circonvent this problem..

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to do this.**

1. Take screenshot of the captcha image web element and try to find the text inside the image using `tesseract` which uses `OCR` technique to get text from image.
2. Use third party service like Fast Captcha ([How to bypass image captcha using java selenium automation](https://thedataextractors.com/how-to-bypass-image-captcha-using-selenium-java.html)), which gives you the text from image and you have to paste it in the captcha text box.

> The question I have is, what do you want to achieve by logging into google account using selenium? Google provides various APIs to use their services.